# Is there a concise way to solve $T = S + ( ( S - E ) * N )$ without needing to enter $S$ twice?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

If I have a starting number **S** and an ending number **E**, and it can be repeated **N** times, what will be the final total **T**?

For example:

```
S = 3540
E = 3650
N = 8
```

I can calculate that each step will increase the total by ( **S - E** ) ***110*** and it can have ( **N** ) ***8*** steps.

```
110 * 8 = 880
3540 + 880 = 4420
```

I can write a function similar to:

<strike>T = S + ( ( S - E ) * N )</strike>

```
T = S + ( ( E - S ) * N )
```

and just using a calculator: subtract $S$ from $E$, then multiply that by $N$, and then add that to $S$.

Is there a proper way to do this on a calculator without having to specify $S$ twice?

Comment: I think this is just S*(N+1) -N*E, but then you are entering N twice.

Comment: I messed up and put S - E instead of E - S, and now changing your suggestion to:
`S*(N**-**1) -N*E` works except the answer is negative. I can just ignore that and this would work, but is there a better adjustment of your formula? and entering N twice is much easier than entering S or E twice.

Comment: seems to be `-S*(N-1) +N*E` - thankyou!

Comment: You should either answer your own question below or delete it so that it does not stay on the unanswered queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was deleted, reposting.

```
-S * ( N - 1 ) + N * E
```